# Как на Javascript вывести дату эквивалентную функции PHP date()?

Tags: javascript

Как из такого формата "`1418654531`" времени получить дату и время в виде строки: "`30.07.2018 17:05:02`" ?

Имеем следующие данные:

```
var time = 1418654531;
```

Эквивалент на PHP (пример)

```
$datetime = date("d.m.Y H:i:s", time()); // 30.07.2018 17:05:02 или
$datetime = date("d.m.Y H:i:s", 1418654531);
```

Желательно быструю функцию, обработка будет происходит по нескольку миллионов записей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал пока такой способ, наверное это единственный

```
var time = 1418654531;

date = new Date(time * 1000);

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

var datetime = day + '.' + month + '.' + year +' '+ hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать библиотеку [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
   Для примера вывод времени в формате будет такой:

   `moment(time*1000).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');`
2. Если Вам нет нужды тянуть всю библиотеку, то можно изспользовать стандартный js, но преобразовать в другой формат будет немножко посложнее чем в php:

   `` var date = new Date(time * 1000);
    var str = `${date.getDate()}.${date.getMonth() + 1}.${date.getFullYear()} 
      ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getMilliseconds()} ``

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date(1418654531);
console.log(date);//Полная дата
console.log(date.getMonth());//Число месяца
console.log(date.getDate());//Число дня
console.log(date.getFullYear());//Полный год
console.log(date.getHours());//Кол-во часов
console.log(date.getMinutes());//Кол-во минут
console.log(date.getSeconds());//Кол-во сукунд
console.log(date.getMilliseconds());//Кол-во миллисекунд
console.log(date.getTime());//Кол-во миллисекунд с 1 января 1970(равно переданному числу)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить дату из timestamp, достаточно передать переменную в new Date():

```js
var time = 1418654531;
var date = new Date(time);
console.log(date);
```

А чтобы привести её к необходимому виду, можно воспользоваться специальными методами js для форматирования даты/времени. Например:

```js
var time = 1418654531;

var date = new Date(time);

var options = {
 year: 'numeric',
 month: 'numeric',
 day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric'
};

console.log(date.toLocaleString("ru", options));
```

Подробнее об этом - https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime#%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82